# User, family and pivot to access information to and from

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

How can i set up user model with family model to get user->families and family->users in laravel 5?
I am not sure whether to use has many relationships or belongstomany relationship?
Idea is like:
User can have many families
Family can have many users

Also family has an owner user

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat difficult to put any constraints (except, of course, file size) on content during uploading stage, but after uploading you can either use a native java library for media analysing & manipulation (e.g [xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) or [OpenIMAJ](http://openimaj.org)) or call an external tool like ffmpeg on uploaded file to determine it's length and then remove the file if it didnt pass your requirements.